# C preprocessor: redefine macro, macro overload

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The following code has a FLAG controlled macro to use func1 or func2 when compiling. I want to make it switch between the 2 function when compiling by using the "FLAG" macro (defining/undefining) as it's done on main(). This is just a sample/example, the usage will be across multiple files.

My question is that this only executes func1() as the preprocessor have assigned the symbol to func_wrapper and I'm not changing it. Also if if do `#undef func_wrapper`it will be required to redefine it by adding more code.

My question is if it is possible to achieve that without having the redefine of func_wrapper each time. It something like making the preprocessor do another pass over the macros when the FLAG is undefined and check again the defines that where defined under.

I want to get something that looks like the following code:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions2.h"

#define FLAG

#ifdef FLAG
#define func_wrapper func1
#endif


#ifndef FLAG
#define func_wrapper func2
#endif


int main(){

    func_wrapper();


    #undef FLAG

    func_wrapper();

}
```

and runs like the follwing one:

```
...
//same as previous one
...
int main(){

    func_wrapper();


    #undef FLAG
    #ifndef FLAG
    #undef func_wrapper
    #define func_wrapper func2
    #endif

    func_wrapper();

}
```

Comment: no, that's not how the preprocessor works. A function pointer might be what you're actually looking for

Comment: Why was this tagged [assembly]?  GCC can use the C preprocessor on .S assembly files, but your examples are in C source, not asm.  And the C preprocess is just text substitution before compilation proper, so multiple steps removed from the assembly the compiler will eventually make.

Comment: `#ifndef FLAG` right after `#undef FLAG` is the same as `#if 1`. Your "runs like" example seems over-complicated, but I guess that captures the re-evaluation of the earlier ifdef stuff that you wish you could have.

Comment: Consider handling things like different build scenarios through version control, not through the pre-processor. The pre-processor is clunky and should be the last resort. Spewing pre-processor directors all over your code also makes it far less readable.

Answer (score 3):

> if it is possible to achieve that without having the redefine of func_wrapper each time

No.

> making the preprocessor do another pass over the macros

You have to type out that another pass.

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions2.h"

#define FLAG

#ifdef FLAG
#define func_wrapper func1
#else
#define func_wrapper func2
#endif

int main() {
    func_wrapper();
    #undef FLAG
#undef func_wrapper
#ifdef FLAG
#define func_wrapper func1
#else
#define func_wrapper func2
#endif
    func_wrapper();
}
```

You can put that in a header.

```
// resolve_flag.h
#ifdef func_wrapper
#undef func_wrapper
#endif
#ifdef FLAG
#define func_wrapper func1
#else
#define func_wrapper func2
#endif

// main.h
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions2.h"

#define FLAG
#include "resolve_flag.h"

int main() {
    func_wrapper();
    #undef FLAG
    #include "resolve_flag.h"    
    func_wrapper();    
}
```

But maybe just use runtime and some global state:

```
bool flag = 0;
void func_wrapper(void) {
     flag ? func1() : func2();
}

int main() {
     func_wrapper();
     flag = 1;
     func_wrapper();
}
```

Comment: The  #include "resolve_flag.h"    line is the same as adding the "undef-define" macros again, now they are on another file...

Comment: @nickname23: That's correct; you need a new `#define func_wrapper` to actually be there, where you change FLAG.  Putting them in another file means slightly less clutter at each FLAG-change location.  CPP macros can't AFAIK re-evaluate some other macro every time they expand, to control how they expand.

Comment: Any `#include "file"` is exactly the same as just pasting the file content.

Answer (score 1):

If `func_wrapper` is *not* originally a macro, you can redefine it to something else with only one line of source:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions2.h"

// default definition.  We can use macros to have some callers call func2 directly
static inline void func_wrapper() {
  func1();
}
// #define func_wrapper func2


int main()
{
    func_wrapper();    //  call func1
    #define func_wrapper func2
    func_wrapper();    //  call func2

    #undef func_wrapper  // now it's back to an alias for func1
}
```

This is rather ugly and seems pretty hacky, and loses the separate name of FLAG which presumably has some useful semantic meaning.  I wouldn't recommend doing this.

If the function actually takes args, your wrapper would have to pass them on.

---

You actually don't need CPP at all if you can use nested functions, a GNU C extension.  This works in GCC but not clang ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYgkAVlIAB1QFQlsGZzcPPVj4mwFffyCWUPCuKMtMa0ShAiZiAmT3Ty4LTCtMhnLKgmzAkLCJaQUKqprU%2Br62jtz8noBKC1RXYmR2DgA3VDx0AGoqVwZkLggVtcmAUgBmACEjjQBBA42tnYAmfdX0Y/PLq4%2BRm2R1v1o/Jh1rdNttkMYAO7EJjRaJhCCTdZHADsF2u61BOz2bzRn2RABEPgB6IlIh4nLA0fyY8FQmFw4g0h4fFnXPwEdYsJh%2BBEs1EfDEY%2B606Gw%2BE41lXQXAl40yGihm81FM3nnJEEjEk9YKBBMdCoCEKdYEBBA4C0VDBMTrSl%2BBICSXS4Xy%2Bni064lGE64caa0TgRXieDhaUioTiObWzeZAo7knikAiaH3TADWIBOJwAdBmc7m8/pOJJeCwJBoNKQgyGwxxeAoQOXE8GfaQ4LAkGgWNE6GFyJQO136OFkMAuCd6lglngFgA1PCYCEAeThQfjNFoBDCdYgwSTpGCfkqAE9OPH98xiIeF8FtCVG/GO2xBAuGLRj03SFguUZxO/8MRb3gSyYHW76YKoJSuBuJ68OyjS7gCwTQhezhYNBCbEHgJbcM2VAGMACizvOS6MGh/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqO%2Buj1AYRggKYxjmAhdaQNMqDRM0IEALQLic6yCQA6mItC1o0AF2BADiDHUpA%2BIC4zdPU6T2kkLi1GkcTaWMXQFA0TRlP01S6UMplyS0FlGXkGkWBZSl6CMVQORMXDTAoUYLHoEKGAQS4EAAkgw/DQb6/qBru1brKoAAcABsgnJZI6zAMgvyjpmXDrBAuCECQZJjpMvCNlokzTKaerdAipBphm2Z5q1GYFhwRYVnFnC1vWCZJtMrZQDAiAoKgnbdmQFAQP2U0oMgLEjslZYfpgk4znOi7LqRdAbsQW47u%2BZ5HmhJ0XleN7WGhD6MMFL5viGn6GOaixPXg/6lEBIEhmBEFQdh5CCHB74IUhh4oYs8YEBhWE8NMuFMPhhHbSRgNkcIojiNRGN0Wou66A8%2BgvWxZj6HgwTcQ1fECZwwmiRJUliX06CnPiwAMK4XDIjJZnyYpVnKapOTGfpGSJK5mkGc0nlOcUpQCK0AyC25skK3ZoxqaLwwuSrOuayLjkFD5flUaQgVPvx4WRdh0UcAG3XvvFSWpel6yLS96xcMlmYaL7BVFUQjKxmVFWDam6ZZm1bUdV1JYROWla8NWfUNoNLajRASCzAQ0SQb2s0TQOYQBKwiwu2lGUe0YXs%2B37v34EHax6BjFHY9IuNKPjjEgETdLRFFHUO0noacAukF5xyqBUAlKWV%2B7S2177/sQM4k2DqVDzlQNTbVaQtVYOEDV%2Bp1xYgAnjtVr1Fj9ZVyaNZHLXR7mHUnLFTvX3fe8nw879XzWO8qrTCAgdRIIBJBAA%3D%3D)).

```
// default definition
static inline void func_wrapper() {
  func1();
}

int main()
{
    func_wrapper();

    static inline void func_wrapper(){ func2(); }  // shadows the global definition

    func_wrapper();
}
```

This is even worse, since the wrapper definition clutters up the function you're using it inside.